# Uncaught ReferenceError: li is not defined

Tags: javascript

This is to do list project, but I don't know why this isn't working.

Can anyone help me? I have checked this several times, and all files are good. Also, CSS code is not mine, it's copied.

Of course, this project is not finished, but I'm testing this now (I'm beginner).

I got this error when I click on span:

```
script.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: li is not defined
    at newTask (script.js:4:2)
    at HTMLSpanElement.onclick (index.html:14:46)
```

```js
function newTask() {
    let task = document.createElement('li');
    let inputText = document.querySelector('#inputText').value;
    li.appendChild(inputText)
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 250px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

ul li.checked {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

ul li.checked::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 15px;
  width: 7px;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Clear floats after the header */
.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Style the input */
input {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* Style the "Add" button */
.addBtn {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.addBtn:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> To Do List </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="task-manager" class="header">
        <h2 style="margin:5px"> Lista zadataka </h2>
        <input type="text" id="inputText" placeholder=" Naziv zadatka ">
        <span onclick="newTask()" class="addBtn">Dodaj</span>
    </div>

    <ul id="list">

    </ul>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the variable is named `task` not `li`.

Comment: If `task = document.createElement('li')`, then instead of `li.appendChild()`, try rather `task.appendChild()`.

Comment: You're also never appending the task to the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to get the  `ul` element which has `list` id, also you need to set the value of the `li` element after create it with `input` value.

Also, If wanted to reset the input value after adding the `task`

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#inputText')
function newTask() {
    let task = document.createElement('li');
    
    let inputText = input.value;
    task.textContent = inputText;
    input.value = ''
    const list = document.getElementById('list');
    list.appendChild(task)
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 250px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

ul li.checked {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

ul li.checked::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 15px;
  width: 7px;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Clear floats after the header */
.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Style the input */
input {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* Style the "Add" button */
.addBtn {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.addBtn:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> To Do List </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="task-manager" class="header">
        <h2 style="margin:5px"> Lista zadataka </h2>
        <input type="text" id="inputText" placeholder=" Naziv zadatka ">
        <span onclick="newTask()" class="addBtn">Dodaj</span>
    </div>

    <ul id="list">

    </ul>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should decalare `input` inside the `newTask` or add a `function parameter` : `input`

Comment: Why should I do that?

Comment: Ussualy concidered as "not the best" practice, it make the function less flexible, less reable ( as you don't know where this variable is declared ) and occording to some benchmark less efficient. After all this is just an opinion, you are free to do as you wish ;)